# Is it ok to scale down UIImage's?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I've been told not to scale down images, but always to use them in their original resolution.

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has a 'Respond Action' on the cell. The UIImageView in Storyboard is 16x16.

Now originally I was using a 256x256 image, and my UIImageView has an Aspect Ratio constraint, and a height constraint of 16.

Then it was suggested to me to not ever scale down images, but to use an image that fit the exact size I needed. So a 16x16 was designed for me, and I used that. It looks awfully blurry though.

The results are here (The font next to it is 11.0 point to give you an idea of it's size):

[image]

What is the correct way to go about this? Should you not scale down images? What is the reason? It looks much better than the 16x16.

Answer (score 1):

Scale your image down before adding it to your project...

Take your 256x256 png image and scale it to 1x, 2x, and 3x size.
1x should equal the size that you need your image to display in the view.
2x and 3x will support retina and retina HD displays.

ex:

Name: image.png | Size: 16x16

Name: image@2x.png | Size: 32x32

Name: image@3x.png | Size: 48x48

Drop these images into your `Images.xcassets`

see: [Specifying High-Resolution Images in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW17)

also: [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't **need** to scale down images, but it's a good idea.  If you're cramming a 256x256 in a 16x16 means the user is downloading 65kb vs <1kb of data.  Or if it's in your bundle, then your app is that much 'heavier'.

But it depends what screen resolution you're using.  Even an iPhone 4 uses retina, which means your 16x16 image view should contain a 32x32 image.  You should also supply a 48x48 for iPhone 6+ screens.  This will make your images look great on each screen size.

Use `Images.xcassets` to manage your images.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't scale down the images ideally, but you also need to cosier the screen resolution. Old devices are 1x, retina devices are 2x and he latest iPhone 6 devices use 3x images which means you should have 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48 images to be used by each device (preferably managed in an image asset). What you're seeing at the moment is a 1x image being scaled up to 2x or 3x so it's blurry. Previously you had a large image scaled down which is bad for memory usage but looks sharp.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an image from your asset catalog, provided to yourself during development. You don't want to scale down images at runtime as it will add unnecessary  overhead to your app. Rather have the assets sized to the required dimensions and add them to your xcimage catalog for 1x, 2x and 3x displays. Think optimisation in terms of memory and bundle size, what's the minimum size required to make it work and look good? If your image is being displayed in a 20x20 square, the optimal sizes will always be 20x20, 40x40 and 60x60 for 1x, 2x and 3x displayed.

Now fetching images from the network is an entirely different ballgame. You will find that sometimes you **might** want to scale down the image, but only when the image you fetch is bigger than what you need to display, like when you're trying to fit in a 2000x2000px image in a  36x26px square. You want to do the scale down for three reasons:

- it will reduce virtual memory usage.
- it will reduce storage memory if you persist the image.
- you will save yourself from image downsampling artifacts that appear when the system tries to render the image at runtime.

Best thing to do here is to scale down the image as soon as you download from the network and before using it anywhere within your app.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a purist answer for this and then the answer which saves you from spending your life converting images all day.

The following is a discussion on the topic of scaling.

[iOS - Different images based on device OR scaling the same image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732605/ios-different-images-based-on-device-or-scaling-the-same-image/28732799#28732799)

If you want to avoid having to create too many images, then using x2 images with a resolution of x2 the expected point size usage is a reasonable compromise as that covers the majority of current devices. You would only then be scaling down for iPhone 3s and up for iPhone 6+. You only need large XxY images if you expect to use large images. Again I would go for x2 resolution for those. Often worth having an iPhone and iPad version of an image in case your expect usage on iPad is to use a bigger XxY point size.

As noted in the link, the impact of scaling depends on the image. I would only worry about the images you think look bad when scaled. So far I have not found scaling to be an issue and much easier than creating lots of bespoke PNGs.

Answer (score 0):

Scale it down before set it:

Swift extension:

```
extension UIImage{

        // returns a scaled version of the image
        func imageScaledToSize(size : CGSize, isOpaque : Bool) -> UIImage{

            // begin a context of the desired size
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, isOpaque, 0.0)

            // draw image in the rect with zero origin and size of the context
            let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size)
            self.drawInRect(imageRect)

            // get the scaled image, close the context and return the image
            let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return scaledImage
       }
}
```

Example:

```
aUIImageView.image = aUIImage.imageScaledToSize(aUIImageView.bounds.size, isOpaque : false)
```

Set isOpaque to true if the image has no alpha: drawing will have better performance.